# Нужна помощь в написание теста (TestNG) для обычного forEach но с возвращаемым значением void

Tags: java

Необходимо написание теста (TestNG) для обычного forEach но с возвращаемым значением void (не могу понять, как проверять данный метод):

```
@Override
public <E> List<E> fill(Supplier<E> producer, int count) {
    return Stream.generate(producer).limit(count).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```